# Handling a radio button array in php

Tags: php, dynamic, radio-button

I have a bit of PHP code that is really taking a toll on me. To simplify, I have a table where three of the columns are foreign keys (**event_type, accommodation_type and public_user**). I am dynamically creating a set of radio buttons and I have set the ID attribute on each input value correctly.

```
                        $result2 = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM event_type", $connection);
                        if(!$result2){
                            die("Database query failed: " . mysql_error());
                        }
                        $event = mysql_fetch_array($result2);   

                    echo "<input type='radio' name='event_type' value='";
                    echo $event["id"];
                    echo "' >&nbsp;&nbsp;";
                    echo $event['name'];
                    echo "</input><br /><br />";$result4 = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM accommodation_type", $connection);

                        if(!$result4){
                            die("Database query failed: " . mysql_error());
                        }
                        while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result4)){
                            if($row["id"] == 7 || $row["id"] == 8){
                            echo"<tr><td>";
                            echo $row["name"] ;
                            echo"</td><td>$";
                            echo $row["price"];
                            echo ".00</td><td>";
                            echo "<input type='radio' name='accommodation_type' value='";
           echo $row["id"];
                            echo "' />";
                            echo "</td></tr>";
                            }
                        }
```

I retrieved the correct id from the query. Thus after submitting the form with POST, I go on to do some minor validation and prepped the names from my post as follows:

```
    $event_type = trim(mysql_prep($_POST['event_type']));
    $accommodation_type= trim(mysql_prep($_POST['accommodation_type']));
    $public_user = trim(mysql_prep($_POST['public_user']));
    $comments = trim(mysql_prep($_POST['comments']));
    $grand_total = trim(mysql_prep($_POST['grand_total']));
```

I then proceeded to write insert statements to insert the data into the relevant tables. This requires two queries as follows.

```
        $query = "INSERT INTO event_registration (event_type, accommodation_type, public_user, comments, grand_total) VALUES ('{$event_type}','{$accommodation_type}','{$public_user}','{$comments}','{$grand_total}')";
        $query1 = "INSERT INTO additional_member (first_name, last_name, gender, age_group, public_user) VALUES ('{$first_name}','{$last_name}','{$gender}','{$age_group}','{$public_user}')";
        $result = mysql_query($query, $connection);
        $result1 = mysql_query($query1, $connection);
```

The query1 works as expected, however the first query fails to insert the data. It says undefined index at the lines where I have

```
    $event_type = trim(mysql_prep($_POST['event_type']));
    $accommodation_type= trim(mysql_prep($_POST['accommodation_type']));
```

I am not entirely sure where things went wrong. Everything seems to be set up correctly and the data from the form just refuses to be saved.

Any ideas ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

why not try reviewing the code from scratch and see if there are any syntax errors and then move on.

Comment: Syntax errors, flow control have been plaguing the code. We reviewed the code and rebuilt it from the ground up and now it works as expected.

Answer (score 0):

You are creating accommodation type

```
 echo "<input type='radio' name='accommodation_type' value='";
       echo $row["id"];
```

But not echoing `event_type` anywhere. Try echoing that too:

```
 echo "<input type='radio' name='accommodation_type' value='";
       echo $row["id"];

 echo "<input type='radio' name='event_type' value='";
       echo $row["whatever"];
```

Comment: Sorry for omitting this part, I have edited the question above to include this part. It was already done and the error continues to persist.

Kind regards.

Comment: Now i could suggest couple of things: make sure that there is also a FORM tag enclosing these inputs and second make sure that you are using the appropriate form array eg $_POST, to see that's what you have defind in FORM attribute.

Comment: yes this was infact done as follows <form  action="eventregistration.php" method="post" id="form1"> 

I thnk the problem stems from the validation because the both errors also refer to a function used for our validation.

Comment: not sure but if those two lines are inside function, put this as first line in your function: global $_POST;

Comment: You are getting those errors due to your POST array, it seems your calling the wrong values, which throws undefined index.

Comment: Well actually after the POST I was able to echo the values because I tested if the method from the server was post then show the form else echo the following:

echo "The event type" . $_POST['event_type'];
echo $_POST['accommodation_type'];

This worked perfectly. And this is the confusing part If it is being posted correctly why is it not hitting the dadabase table

Comment: ok, see what error mysql gives: $result = mysql_query($query, $connection) or die(mysql_error());

Comment: after the queries i have the following checks implemented.

if($result && $result1){
 $message = "The User was successfully registered";
} else{
  $message = "The User could not be registered";
  $message .= "<br />" . mysql_error();
}

Comment: Actually, the `accommodation_type` and `event_type` variables are coming empty, that's why you are getting undefined index error, you need to check bit by bit what is the place where they get empty.

Comment: this is quite accurate, you see we have two radio buttons for selecting the event_type...its one or the other. I just tried using the other option while testiing, but an undefined index error was generated. I really think we need to revisit the way we are constructing thr fields on the forn.